# Swift reverse array not working

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, reverse

I try to make reversed array, please consider following:

```
let arrValues : [MyStruct] = 
            [MyStruct(key: "id-5"),     
             MyStruct(key: "id-10"),
             MyStruct(key: "id-20")]

let reversedKeys = arrValues.map{$0.key ?? ""}.reversed()
```

it suppose to work, but in  log i see keys in same order i did add them.

Comment: @the4kman yes, what is wrong with that

Comment: Does the output look like this: `ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Array<String>>(_base: ["id-5", "id-10", "id-20"])`? Because that's expected; you're getting back a reversed *view* onto the mapped array, not a new reversed array. If you want a reversed array, then say `let reversedKeys: Array = arrValues.map{$0.key ?? ""}.reversed()`.

Comment: Related: [Why does the reverse() function in the Swift standard library return ReverseRandomAccessCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558390/why-does-the-reverse-function-in-the-swift-standard-library-return-reverserand).

Comment: @MartinR thanks, bookmarked

Comment: @Hamish thanks, still i think this is kind of weird :)

Comment: `arrValues.reversed().map{$0.key ?? ""}` should also produce an array.

Comment: @MartinR what's the difference..

Comment: [`Sequence.map()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905795-map) has an array as return type.

Answer (score 4):

Well this is a easy test for the playground:

```
import UIKit

struct MyStruct {
    var key: String?
}

let arrValues : [MyStruct] = [MyStruct(key: "id-5"), MyStruct(key: "id-10"), MyStruct(key: "id-20")]

let reversedKeys = arrValues.map{$0.key ?? ""}.reversed()
for key in reversedKeys {
    debugPrint(key)
}
```

The debugPrint will show correctly: `"id-20" "id-10" "id-5"`

But if you stop the execution and debug the contents of reversedKeys it will show `id-5 id-10 id-20`

There are two functions `reverse()` and `reversed()`.

`reversed()` doesn't actually reorder the array. It just returns an object (like an iterator) which iterates the elements from the end to the start. It has a complexity of O(1).

However `reverse()` changes the order of the elements, complexity of O(n). But it has to be a mutable array cause is a mutating function, so following the example you will need to do something like this:

```
var mutableCopy = arrValues
mutableCopy.reverse()
let reverseKeys = mutableCopy.map{$0.key ?? ""}
for key in reverseKeys {
    debugPrint(key)
}
```

If you just need to iterate the keys use `reversed()`, but if you have to access the keys with a subscript like `reverseKeys[2]`, then you should use `reverse()`