# what's the time complexity of swift reversed?

Tags: arrays, swift, time-complexity

I have read apple developer document:

[Array.reverse()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2943836-reverse)

[Array.reversed()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1690025-reversed)

the fist article points out: Complexity: O(n), where n is the number of elements in the collection.

the second article points out: Complexity: O(1), and without any reason.

Is that just a little mistake or other reason?

Because second article takes a example for

```
let word = "Backwards"
for char in word.reversed() {
    print(char, terminator: "")
}
// Prints "sdrawkcaB"
```

I think O(n) is correct answer. right?

Comment: Related: [Why does the reverse() function in the Swift standard library return ReverseRandomAccessCollection?
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34558390/1187415).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a key importance between the two methods. `reverse()` mutates the `Array` in place, so its time complexity has to be `O(n)` since it needs to exchange the order of all elements.

However, on the other hand, if you check the return type of `reversed()`, it is `ReversedCollection<Array<Element>>` and the documentation clearly states that instead of returning a new `Array` instance, the `reversed()` method returns a wrapper type that simply contains the original array and provides access to its elements in reverse order. This wrapper type, `ReversedCollection` can be created in constant time, hence the time complexity of `reversed()` is `O(1)`.

The example code you mention obviously has `O(n)` time complexity, since `word.reversed()` is traversed using a loop, however, the time complexity mentioned in the documentation simply relates to the function call, `word.reversed()`, which is indeed `O(1)` for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: is it the same principle of Circular linked list?

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz there's no such built-in type in Swift, so I can't really refer to that, since it's rather an implementation detail than a principle of a data structure in the case of `reverse()` and `reversed()`

Answer (score 2):

***Is that just a little mistake or other reason?***

***I think O(n) is correct answer. right?***

No, `reverse()` actually takes `O(n)` and `reversed()` `O(1)`.

The example is a little bit confusing, but you should better separate it into two parts.

```
let word = Array("Backwards")
let reversedWord = word.reversed() //<- O(1) is the complexity of this operation.
for char in reversedWord { //<- This for-in loop, of course is O(n)
    print(char, terminator: "")
}
// Prints "sdrawkcaB"
```

In case of `reverse()`:

```
var word = Array("Backwards")
word.reverse() //<- This operation takes O(n)
for char in word {
    print(char, terminator: "")
}
// Prints "sdrawkcaB"
```